# how to select non repeated date intervals?

Tags: sql, database

My products table,

```
year
2014
2013
2012
2011
2010
2009
2008
2007
2006
2005
2004
2003
2002
2001
2000
```

My Query,

```
SELECT dt||'-'||dt1 
FROM
(SELECT year as dt, year+4 as dt1
FROM
products 
GROUP BY year);
```

My output,

```
2000-2004
2001-2005
2002-2006
2003-2007
2004-2008
2005-2009
2006-2010
2007-2011
2008-2012
2009-2013
2010-2014
2011-2015
2012-2016
2013-2017
2014-2018
```

expected result,

```
2000-2004 
2005-2009 
2010-2014
```

I'm not getting any clue for generating that date interval.
Any tips and suggestion of **query** will be of great help.
Thanks

Comment: The first interval of your expected result is 4 while the second and third intervals are 5. What is the reason?

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake. I made an edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subtract a modulus 5 from the year and group by that.

```
SELECT (year-(year%5))||'-'||(year-(year%5)+4) AS years
FROM products 
GROUP BY year-(year%5)
```

A modulus N is the remainder when the nearest lower multitude of N is substracted from a number.
For example:

```
11%5 = 11 - 10 = 1 
8%5 = 8 - 5 = 3
```

So by subtracting it from the year you get the nearest multitude of 5

```
2018 - 2018%5 = 2018 - 3 = 2015
```

Another way to round the year down is to divide & multiply it by 5

```
SELECT (CAST(year/5 AS INTEGER)*5)||'-'||MAX(year) AS years
FROM products 
GROUP BY CAST(year/5 AS INTEGER)*5;
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=e48941ddd0be3e6d2f5b0f92b921eda5)*

Comment: For anyone reading this, "subtracting a modulus" is rounding down the `year` to the nearest multiple of "5".

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using [SQLite ROW_NUMBER](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-row_number/) to create a row number column and use this column for the calculation of which records to be retrieved:

```
SELECT t.year ||'-'|| (t.year + 4)
FROM (
    SELECT  *, Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY year) AS RowNumber 
    FROM products
) t
WHERE (t.RowNumber - 1) % 5 = 0
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8NRarug2U4289Rp93om3xM/0)

Comment: Thank you, It works but I find LukStorms answer more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Database Structure and Data

```
CREATE TABLE tablename
(
    `year` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO tablename
VALUES      (2000),
            (2001),
            (2002),
            (2003),
            (2004),
            (2005),
            (2006),
            (2007),
            (2008),
            (2009),
            (2010),
            (2011),
            (2012),
            (2013),
            (2014);
```

SQL Query

```
SELECT ( Min(year) || '-' || Max(year) ) AS Col1
FROM   (SELECT year,
               Row_number() OVER (partition BY year % 5 ORDER BY year) AS RowNumber
        FROM   tablename) tmp
GROUP  BY rownumber
```

Result

```
+-----------+
|   Col1    |
+-----------+
| 2000-2004 |
| 2005-2009 |
| 2010-2014 |
+-----------+
```

Online Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5rHUda17KRtsA3ZAzoLDrE/0

---

<sub>**Reference**

1. SQLite - Operators: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_operators.htm</sub>

Comment: Thank you, It works but I find LukStorms answer more efficient.

Comment: That's okay. I'm happy that one of use was able to help you.